# Advices to implement child comments on comments (How to set it up)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am working with Laravel and have created a morphable comment table with laravel. Now I want to implemnt the reply function so people can answer to comments. I only do need the first level of answering. So, you can answer a comment but you cannot answer on a comment child. There is only one level of comment childs and not 2 or 3 like on Facebook.

My question to you now is, which is the best way to solve this. Because in my laravel view blade I am looping through each comment and want to print my child comments on this commment to (I just don't know how do to his?).

So basically, I would like to know how you would design the table, how you would map it and how you would print it in the view.

Here is my table so far:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `commentable_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `commentable_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `post_status_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  `content` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `comments_commentable_type_commentable_id_index` (`commentable_type`,`commentable_id`),
  KEY `comments_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  KEY `comments_post_status_id_index` (`post_status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `comments_post_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`post_status_id`) REFERENCES `post_statuses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `comments_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: this might help https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-recursive-hasmany-relationship-with-unlimited-subcategories/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child comments should just be more comments except they are mapped to another comment.

Create a comment_children table.

Structure should be:

id: BIGINT
comment_id: BIGINT
child_id: BIGINT

Then you can create a hasManyThrough children relationship on your Comment model and use the comment_children table to match them.

This will allow you to eager load the child comments, you can make your mode always do this by adding:

```
protected $with = [‘children’]
```

You will also want a comments relationship on your PostStatus model.

Set up your model to always load this relationship also by adding:

```
protected $with = [‘comments’]
```

Now whenever you fetch a post, the collection will always contain all the comments and all the children.

Now to access it, something like:

```
$post = Post::where(‘id’, 1)->first()
```

And in your blade:

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
    // display comment
    @foreach($comment->children as $child)
        // display child comments
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Could you replace the smart quotes `‘` with regular ones like `'`? If someone that visits the question and uses your answer and copies it as shown, it will throw a parse error. If they don't know how to do this, your answer won't work for them.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner This answer is to advise, none of it’s content is to be copied. My phone types those quotes, apologies

Comment: *"none of it’s content is to be copied"* - Why? Copy/pasting is used quite often. I doubt anyone will retype that instead of copying.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Why would they even re-type it? It’s an outline of a solution. Why is stack overflow overflowing with people who love to act the way you do, it is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have to just simply two tables if you wanna just 'one level answering'.

First one is 'comment_answer' to contain comments and answers. No extra tables needed for comments and answers because each comment will have one answer, isn`it? So, we can keep each answer in the same record as the question to which it relates. Migration like this;

```
 Schema::create('comment_answer', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->longText('content');
        $table->longText('answer')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_publish')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

> I added columns in simple form, you can add according to your own project..

The second one is 'post_comment_user' for contain post`s and user's relationship with comments and answers. Migration like this

```
Schema::create('post_comment_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('comment_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('comment_id')->references('id')->on('comment_answer')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

> I've simply set up the relationship, you can also use the 'comment_answer' table for users if you want

Then, you can bring comments for the post in your model file ('post') like this;

```
public function get_comments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\comment_answer',
        'post_comment_user',
        'post_id',
        'comment_id')
        ->where('is_publish',1)
        ->orderBy('created_at');
```

and controller like this;

```
$posts=post::where('slug',$post_slug)
        ->with('get_comments')
        ->where('is_publish',1)
        ->firstOrFail();
```

and blade file like this;

```
@foreach($posts->get_comments as $comment)
      {{$comment->content}}
      {{$comment->answer}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Try to keep the names of relationships easy to understand and meaningful. Rather than get_comments, simply call it comments. Imagine doing Post::with(‘get_comments’) as opposed to Post::with(‘comments’)

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 Ok, got it. Thanks a lot.